# how to remove iptables port mirroring rule

Tags: iptables

I don't have much knowledge on `iptables`. I googled the port mirrioring with `iptables`

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 10.20.0.129
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -j TEE --gateway 10.20.0.129
```

sucessfully applied the rules and able see the mirriored traffic. But I dont how to remove that rule. I tried to view the rules, but I cant see the rules

```
veeru@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

OS: Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all mangle `iptables` rules by specification:

```
iptables -t mangle -S
```

This will list the rules as you specified them, for easy copy paste. Replace the `-I` or `-A` with a `-D` to delete them.

To remove those two specific rules type:

```
iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 10.20.0.129
iptables -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -j TEE --gateway 10.20.0.129
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
iptables -t mangle -L
```

-t mangle = access mangle table

-L   =  show list of the rules

to remove all the mangle rules you can use:

```
iptables -t mangle -F
```

-F = flush / delete all rules.